# How can I avoid boilerplate code in Rust?

Tags: rust, dry, code-reuse

I've been writing a hobbyist AES library in Rust and I've run into the problem of eccessive boilerplate code. Basically I represent an AES key with the following struct:

```
pub struct AesKey<const N: usize> {
    data: [u32; N],
}
```

`N` can be any of the following values:

- 4 for 128 bits
- 6 for 192 bits
- 8 for 256 bits

This struct then needs to implement the following trait

```
pub trait AesKeyOps<const N: usize, const N_ROUND_KEYS: usize> {
    // ...
}
```

for each of the possible values of `N`.

And for each of those implementations it needs to implement even more traits for padding, block modes and other implementation logic.

I originally used const generics in my code to make components more reusable, but at a certain point the impl blocks just started to grow exponentially, even though they all contained basically the same code with just some minor tweaks (9 impl blocks for the different padding schemes [3 schemes * 3 key sizes] and the only difference between them are the values for the generics). I tried using an enum as a generic, as that would be able to contain all of the necessary data, but they aren't allowed as any type of generic.

What can I do to avoid repeating code this much while using generics in rust?

Comment: Use macros maybe?

Comment: Yep! I didn't know how macros worked until just now actually. Thanks for the help, if you repost your comment as an answer I'll happily accept it!

Comment: "hobbyist AES library" would be more clear if written as "I love pain"

Comment: I got everything working in under a couple of days, the only problen where I'm having difficulty is the various block modes, but thats just research that I need to do. Im also not handling key generation as secure randomness is not something I trust myself with

Comment: I'm doing it to try to complete the cryptopals challenge using the snallest number of libraries possible.